# Intersect two function types in Typescript elegantly

Tags: typescript

I've these two function types  ..

```
wrapPageElement?(
  args: WrapPageElementBrowserArgs<DataType, PageContext, LocationState>,
  options: PluginOptions
): React.ReactElement
```

.. and ..

```
wrapPageElement?(
  args: WrapPageElementNodeArgs<DataSet, PageContext>,
  options: PluginOptions
): React.ReactElement
```

So they are almost the same, except the type of `args`. The difference doesn't matter for my use case. I can completely rely in the intersecting type between these two. I've wrote the following type:

```
type Params1 = Parameters<GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement']>
type Params2 = Parameters<GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']>
type Return1 = ReturnType<GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement']>
type Return2 = ReturnType<GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']>
type WrapPageElement = (args: Params1[0] | Params2[0], options: Params1[1] | Params2[1]) => Return1 | Return2;
```

[Here is a minimal reproduction.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2B5MwUHs0DOUAvFLgEYBWEAxsANwBQokUAShAIZ0CicEAWwhpgJMlVoNm4aAHUATpzAxOSCH0HDgAIXm4A7gQjyAgvKRFSAbwj8hIgFzjqdADRRyew8bMWnFF2AAXyYWOUVlVXU7LQA5XAATCF9LKBsYx2dJdzRE5PMCfwk6EMYysKgAcU5gAnIQXQMjeTErRigofQiVNQ17YCcACnaOqE4CpwUlHujNEUbvUwLXEY7cbDxCJ3hkdCwcfAIRgEoSAD52Ll4M4EYg8pkqmrqQAGVXtlaRrumovq0hqsxhMoFNIr0bvEkikVqMyBtDttEKhMAjCCdzpduMB-iI7g9WCpFAICABGMREzhCYDGAgAHmqtXqC2aAG0AOQ-cGzfrsgC6Z2khPGVIIACYKSLqbSGc96u82ByuTNccB%20YKKhxgAh5GhyaQtTq0AAVGSypkNLxszndP43dVC6CG3USg0QbW602Qc0vBVK20QuZqgWO0EBnlaMSDcZ%20WBSsmsgAMfKgAB848TxUm%20e51gcthnRaTWaSU%20nKSSxSW%20adiBdnXq05cPWgxfQgA) This is working, but is it possible to write the type `WrapPageElement` more elegantly or is this the way to go?

### Tl;dr

```
type PluginOptions = object;
type ReactElement = object;
type WrapPageElementBrowserArgs = {element: object, browserArgs: object};
type WrapPageElementNodeArgs = {element: object, nodeArgs: object};


type GatsbyBrowser = {
  wrapPageElement: (
    args: WrapPageElementBrowserArgs,
    options: PluginOptions
  ) => ReactElement
}

type GatsbySSR = {
  wrapPageElement: (
    args: WrapPageElementNodeArgs,
    options: PluginOptions
  ) => ReactElement
}

type Params1 = Parameters<GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement']>
type Params2 = Parameters<GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']>
type Return1 = ReturnType<GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement']>
type Return2 = ReturnType<GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']>
type WrapPageElement = (args: Params1[0] | Params2[0], options: Params1[1] | Params2[1]) => Return1 | Return2;

type WrapPageElement2 = GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement'] & GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']; // not what I need
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WPja5N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Hi @jcalz
Thanks for your comment. I've added a reproducible example.

Comment: The return type should be `Return1 & Return2` since return types are covariant. But why not just write `GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement'] & GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']`?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8ARAN) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer (keeping in mind that what you're doing isn't really intersecting the functions).  If not, please [edit] the example code to show a failing use case.  Note that for a small number of parameters it's going to be easier to just do it manually the way you've done.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is exactly what I need, but it's indeed easier to do it manually. Can you tell me what's the precise word for this instead of "intersecting"? Thank you.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you for your comment. What you mentioned doesn't work because the functions would be combined but not the functions parameter types or return types.

Comment: @Robin Not sure what you mean by that, can you show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Robin I don't know that there *is* a "precise" word for the operation you're doing.  Do you want me to write up an answer with the method I showed, perhaps with a note saying that this would only be worth it for long parameter lists?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @kaya3 I've updated the question. The types `WrapPageElement` and `WrapPageElement2` are not the same.

Comment: @jcalz What you provided is what I asked for. I hoped that there is a shorter version, but there doesn't seem to be one. I would totally accept your answer if you write one. Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a type transformation that takes two function types `T` and `U` and converts them into a single function type where each parameter and return type is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of corresponding parameters and return types from `T` and `U`.

I'll call this transformation `UnionFunctions<T, U>` for want of a better term.  You mentioned "intersecting" the functions, but an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of function types in TypeScript is equivalent to the type of a function with multiple call signatures (i.e., an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)) and is not the same as taking the union of each parameter and the return type.

---

Anyway, one possible approach is this:

```
type UnionTuples<T extends any[], U extends { [K in keyof T]: any }> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | U[K] }    

type UnionFunctions<T extends (...args: any[]) => any, U extends (...args: any) => any> =
  (...args: UnionTuples<Parameters<T>, Parameters<U>>) => ReturnType<T> | ReturnType<U>
```

Here `UnionTuples<T, U>` takes two tuples `T` and `U` and produces a single tuple where each element is the union of the corresponding elements from `T` and `U`.  So `UnionTuples<[1, 2], [3, 4]>` should be `[1 | 3, 2 | 4]`.  It's a straightforward [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Then `UnionFunctions` just uses `UnionTuples` on the parameter list from `T` and `U` (using [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)) and the return type is a union of the return types using [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).

It's not incredibly verbose to define `UnionFunctions`, but it takes more characters to write that than it does to do the manual version.  You'd want to use `UnionFunctions` multiple times or with long parameter lists before it would be worth it.

---

Let's see if it works for your example:

```
type WrapPageElement = UnionFunctions<
  GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement'], 
  GatsbySSR['wrapPageElement']
>
/* type WrapPageElement = (
     args: WrapPageElementBrowserArgs | WrapPageElementNodeArgs, 
     options: PluginOptions
 ) => ReactElement */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2B5MwUHs0DOUAvFAN5QCGAXFAIxQC+A3AFCiRQBKElAxsACicCAFsIaYCXJVaAJiZsO0AOoAnSmBiUkEYWInAAQmtwB3AhDUBBNUiKkKEEeMm1cAIwBWEAQBooD1MLK1t7d29fKRZ2cFUNLR09F0MAOVwAEwgwhxlnAzcoTx9-KDRM7LsCCJLotlZYzgBxSmACDxATc0s1aTJWKCgzBO1dfVdgWgAKAcGqKtp1TVHkguNgnpy-WcHcbDxCWnhkdCwcfAJZgEoSAD5uXgFxw1ZGBuUoFraOgGUfrj6s2GyySz0KMzm83CUCWiTGKUk6SyWx2RX2FyOiFQmHRhGudwe-CECOArwajWgAFU0AcACoIMAiAgAHlpUAgAA9gBIMkRKGgQABtAC6AUp7K5PKIFEFAGkoOgoABrCAgXAAMygtOFtH5ICY92Isxl8sVKrVmu1tFpcuFUAAPlBKbamOSPtSDgAxBBoAQHFlsznctC8qBTAB0kcoCyoApFN2I9z1YolwdDEajMb1CaTAsNswz4ej0I9+HpjIgLO0GnE3LUAduAWrlFrVhZlNutxzD2ACDUaFpcVZ90dPF7-cHkGZHfecRhI1BJOkpbQ3t950IzK+7U6GysgoA5MC4asJgfRZ9Wju-lxD8eVmDgOfbqwAPQAKigH1hD6XRqmxbVPOILwmsXQhDYVQOsBJ6PkilT2AEewbkBxzYmc-rdjwRKPqw76vg0QA)